# node js return received data in-rest api response

Tags: node.js, rest, express

i create simple rest api to return media file

```
var fs = require('fs')
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
app.get('/file.ogg', function (req, res) {
    res.set({
      'Content-Type': 'audio/ogg',
      'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'
    });

    var inputStream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/1.ogg');     
    inputStream.pipe(res);
});

var server = app.listen(3002);
```

if i call http://127.0.0.1:3002/file.ogg

server read file 1.ogg and return it in response.

now i use websocket to get file data from external device

```
socket.on('message', function incoming(message) {

        var data = JSON.parse(message);
        console.log('fileName: ' + data.fileName);
        console.log('fileData : ' + data.fileData.length);

        var path =__dirname + '/_' + data.fileName;
        var buf = Buffer.from(data.fileData, 'base64');

        console.log('buf : ' + buf.length);

        // save data to file
        fs.appendFile(path ,buf ,function(err){
            if(err) throw err;
        });

    });
```

i want to return data (buf) in response like first example but without saving any think, how i can do this.

Answer (score 0):

If your files are large, you may want to pull in an additional websocket streaming library which will allow you to stream the data back to the client. [socket.io-stream](https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-stream) was created specifically to allow that. From their examples:

```
// send data
ss(socket).on('file', function(stream) {
  fs.createReadStream('/path/to/file').pipe(stream);
});

// receive data
ss(socket).emit('file', stream);
stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('file.txt'));
```

Comment: there is 2 devices A & B, A send message to B with WS (websocket) ,if i use this command i will send received message to A.

Comment: Updated answer, but I'm still not entirely sure about what you're trying to do. Once you get the message from device A, where do you want to send a response back to? Where's the client in that scenario? Is the file data going back to the requesting socket (device A), or a different server/client?

Comment: client is browser like first example, in the first example i read from file, but now i want to read from websocket